# Google Scripts Web App: How to View User Session

Tags: session, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script (GAS) to host a web app. I would like to be able to see the "session" so that if the user opens the page more than once, I can see the session information for the given user/browser. I currently control all that on the client side, but it would be MUCH neater if it were all on the server side (for example, what if an error occurs when fetching the page?). This is especially important for properly handling user logins... it's so ugly handling it all on the client side.

I'm used to applications like ASP, ASP.NET, and PHP which have sessions and session variables. Does GAS have anything like that for their web apps? Thanks!

**EDIT**: To be clear, I'm running the web app as `Me`, so I can't tell who is logged in by their Google account. Users don't need a Google account to access the page.

Comment: You should use PropertiesService and store information either in User or Script properties, depending upon the circumstances.  If you needed to track user information across multiple instances of the Web App being open for example, you might use User properties.  Properties Service does not automatically clear the information when the user logs out, or closes the page.  Cache Service is another and different storage option that is temporary.  Cache will "time out", but there is no "built-in" way to sync when cache service looses it's values and the user stops using your Web App.

Comment: You would need to clear that user's old session information when the Web App loaded, or overwrite it, making sure not to leave any old data in storage.  If the user logs out, or your Web App can detect the page closing, then you could run some server code to clear the session information.

Comment: Detecting when the page is being closed wouldn't be hard. I'd actually prefer it be based on an expiration date anyways.  However, I'm not sure how using the `PropertiesService` would help. I still would have no idea whose session this is when the page is loading, right? Maybe I didn't make it clear that the script is executing as `Me`, not as a Google user. So I wanted to be able to differentiate by browser session since the Google side of things is anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the video on using google analytics in google apps script. It was presented by one of the top App Script developers who uses this technique in his tools. It allows tracking users actions/errors individually and in aggregate.

> https://youtu.be/r_S7NeidzI0?t=1869

Comment: Would you be able to summarize what they're referring to? Also, don't you have to pay for Google Analytics? I'm looking for a free solution here...

Comment: Analytics is free. Well there is the 150k a year tier, but you don't need that.  I wasn't really giving an answer, I just wanted to point out a resource. 
Also a heads up Apps Script Early Access Program includes google cloud logging. You may want to sign up for that. It gives by user 30 day persistent logging in the free tier and longer as a payed service.